# xamarin android Binding events

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

[image]The following is the KT code, but after I bind the DLL, without this event, how should I bind it? To have callback functions?

Kotlin code

```
sstp.setOnConnectStatusListener(object : SSTPUtils.OnConnectStatusListener{
override fun status(code: Int, msg: String) {
Log.i("连接状态", "状态码：$code，信息：$msg")
}
})
```

I asked my friend to compile the jar for me, I use xamarin to call, there is nothing wrong with the current call, but I did not bind the conversion of the event, who will switch?

jar download
https://github.com/bbhxwl/xamarinAndroidSSTP

The binding does not know why it does not generate the event setOnConnectStatusListener

Comment: can you show the code of the generated sstp class? Usually eventlisteners are converted to C# events